# How can i present different webview based on localization?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, localization

I have app that i want to localize for multiple languages. The terms and conditions page is web address, and for each language I support it has different link.

In a controller where I present that web view, how can i "localize" this link, that is switch links based on locale?

Comment: YOu just define the links as string with key and value format.In your localizable.string you define the link with key as url , and you just use it as NSLOcalizedString(@"url",nil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build off of Randy's answer you'd want to have the following code to get the site:

Objective-C:

```
// Getting the URL for the language
NSString *websiteString = NSLocalizedString(@"website", nil);

// Calling said URL
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: websiteString]]];
```

Swift:

```
// Getting the URL for the language
let websiteString = NSLocalizedString("website", comment: "language");

// Calling said URL
UIWebView.loadRequest(webviewInstance)(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: websiteString)!))
```

And in your `Localizable.strings` file for a language:

```
// "language" would differ for the various supported languages
"website" = "https://destination.com/language";
```

Answer (score 1):

As Teja Nandamuri commented, you can simply define the links in your `Localizable.strings` files.

For instance, if you support two languages, let's say english and french, you'll have something like :

In your `Localizable.strings (English)` file :

`"my_terms_url" = "https://mywebsite.com/my_terms/en";`

In your `Localizable.strings (French)` file :

`"my_terms_url" = "https://mywebsite.com/my_terms/fr";`